# Python - Get list/dictionary from one class, do the modification in another class and return the modify value to first class

Tags: python-3.x

## first.py

```py
class A():
    lst = [2,2,1]
```

## second.py

```py
from first import A
class B():
    new_lst = A.lst
    new_lst.remove(1)
    #new_lst = [2,2]
```

Now how can i update new_list value from class B to class A
so that class A, lst=[2,2]

Please help me out.

Comment: When you call `new_lst = A.lst` you're not actually copying the values inside of that variable from `A`, you've just created a reference to the variable. So if you modify `new_lst` insidef of `B` the values inside of `A.lst` should be changed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this as a comment at first, but I might as well write a complete answer for it. When you call `new_lst = A.lst` you're not actually copying the values inside of `A.lst`. What's happening is that you're creating a pointer to the variable inside of `A`.

We can demonstrate this by adding a couple of lines inside of **second.py**:

```
from first import A
class B:
    new_lst = A.lst

print(f'A: {A.lst}, B: {B.new_lst}') #Output: A: [1, 2, 3], B: [1, 2, 3]
B.new_lst.append("testing")
print(f'A: {A.lst}, B: {B.new_lst}') #Output: A: [1, 2, 3, 'testing'], B: [1, 2, 3, 'testing']
A.lst.remove(3)
print(f'A: {A.lst}, B: {B.new_lst}') #Output: A: [1, 2, 'testing'], B: [1, 2, 'testing']
```

As you can see, if we add a new variable to `B.new_lst` it's also added to `A.lst` likewise when we remove a value from `A.lst`.

Comment: Thanks for you response. Also, how class A will get updated value of list from class B?

Comment: As I've demonstrated in the code above, when updating `B.new_lst` the change will automatically happen to the variable `A.lst` because the two variable-names point to the same location in memory.

Comment: But how it is possible when I have two different python classes

Comment: What do you mean? The example above is using two classes. `A` is the class you created in your file **first.py**. Could you please clarify exactly what you're trying to accomplish here? It feels like what you're asking is not the original problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: There are two different py file(First.py and second.py). Second.py takes list from first.py, perform some modifications. Now how can the first.py file get the updated value of the list from second.py?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to rewrite the file **first.py** itself with the new variables? Whatever you're trying to accomplish doing this, this is not a way to solve the problem. Dynamically changing the code will only create more complex code, and will also open yourself up to security issues if the file you're writing to is modified to run malicious code.